# DateTimeFormat.parse() failure

Tags: parsing, gwt, datetime-format

Code:

```
    DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat
            .getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

    Date date = dateFormat.parse("Wed May 30 18:33:22 PDT 2012");
```

Result:

```
Uncaught java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wed May 30 18:33:22 PDT 2012
```

Why?

I've checked and doublechecked my pattern against [the docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html). Plugging the pattern into a [SimpleDateFormat tester](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm) gives the expected results as well, although that's obviously not a conclusive test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing of the date has limited support as per the [docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) you mentioned:

> The time zone support for parsing is limited. Only standard GMT and RFC format are supported. Time zone specification using time zone id (like America/Los_Angeles), time zone names (like PST, Pacific Standard Time) are not supported.

More specifically

> In the current implementation, timezone parsing only supports
>   GMT:hhmm, GMT:+hhmm, and GMT:-hhmm.

So, the following code works fine:

```
    DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat
            .getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("Thu May 31 09:45:21  GMT-07:00 2012");
    GWT.log("Date "+date);
```